# Why Tangency portfolio for 4 stocks not giving short selling ratio using fPortfolio library in R

Tags: r, finance, stock, portfolio

I am using four stocks i.e. Sunpharma, Maruti,IciciBank and TCS and trying to find the optimal weightage of all the stocks using tangency portfolio in the efficient frontier. When I pass the returns dataset for last 60 months in the following code:

```
library(timeSeries)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(fPortfolio)

portfolio <- read.csv("c:\\SharePrice.csv")
timeseries_portfolio <- timeSeries(portfolio[,4:6],portfolio[,1])
stockret <- returns(timeseries_portfolio)
tangencyPortfolio(stockret, spec = portfolioSpec(),constraints ="short")
```

I do not get the output in the short selling even if I pass constraints ="short". It basically forces short selling to 0 and then the ratio is given for remaining 3 stocks.

```
Portfolio Weights:
Sun.Pharma     Maruti ICICI.Bank        TCS 
    0.1222     0.4329     0.0000     0.4450
```

However when I do it using manual method of coding it gives -1.33 for IciciBank, that means tangency portfolio actually suggesting to short sell the IciciBank stock but the library is giving incorrect result.

I want to understand how to allow short selling in the tangency portfolio R code which is present in fPortfolio library. Weird thing is when I consider only 3 stocks in the portfolio it gives correct weightage which matches with my manual code without using library.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, you will need to provide the keyword argument `constraints="Short"`.  So my bet is that once you fix the typo, the weight will become negative, assuming everything upstream is all "as expected" and the source data you used to compute manually is the same as the input you provided to the code.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fPortfolio/versions/280.73/topics/portfolioConstraints